# Декоратор для рекурсии

Tags: python, рекурсия, декоратор

У меня есть декоратор, подсчитывающий количество вызовов рекурсивной функции (`ncalls`) и глубину рекурсии (`rdepth`)

Для не рекурсивной функции значения будут (1,1)

На примерах, которые придумала я, и на примерах из контекста работает правильно, но при сдаче в контексте не проходит один тест, но я никак не могу придумать ситуацию, которая бы сломала мой код.

`counter.flag` и `counter.w` (не зануляется только когда вышли из функции столько же раз, как глубоко заходили) нужны чтобы понимать, когда мы в данную функцию заходим первый раз и когда нужно сбросить счетчики, `counter.d` считает глубину рекурсии в текущий момент

```
def counter(func):
    counter.flag = True
    counter.w = 0
    counter.d = 0

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def count_f(*args, **kwargs):
        if counter.flag:
            count_f.ncalls = 0
            count_f.rdepth = 0
            counter.flag = False
            counter.w = 0
            counter.d = 0
        count_f.ncalls += 1
        counter.d += 1
        counter.w = 0
        if count_f.rdepth < counter.d:
            count_f.rdepth = counter.d
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        counter.d -= 1
        counter.w += 1
        if counter.w == count_f.rdepth:
            counter.flag = True
        return result

    return count_f
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь можно сделать?

Пример

```
@counter
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)

fib(3)
print(fib.ncalls, fib.rdepth)
# 5 3
```

Пример из контеста:

```
@counter
def func2(n, steps):
    if steps == 0:
        return

    func2(n + 1, steps - 1)
    func2(n - 1, steps - 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func2(0, 5)
    print(func2.ncalls, func2.rdepth)

    func2(0, 3)
    print(func2.ncalls, func2.rdepth)
# 63 6
# 15 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не привязывайтесь к декоратору, храните все в декорированной функции.

```
def counter(f):
    def reset():
        wrapped.rdepth = 0
        wrapped.ncalls = 0

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        if wrapped.depth == 0:
            reset()

        wrapped.depth += 1
        wrapped.ncalls += 1
        wrapped.rdepth = max(wrapped.rdepth, wrapped.depth)

        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            wrapped.depth -= 1

    wrapped.depth = 0
    reset()
    return wrapped
```

или так, если не хотите хранить лишние поля на виду

```
def counter(f):
    def reset():
        wrapped.rdepth = 0
        wrapped.ncalls = 0

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal depth

        if depth == 0:
            reset()

        depth += 1
        wrapped.ncalls += 1
        wrapped.rdepth = max(wrapped.rdepth, depth)

        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            depth -= 1

    depth = 0
    reset()
    return wrapped
```

`try` / `finally` обновит глубину, даже если при вызове декорируемой функции произойдет ошибка.

```
@counter
def f():
    raise ValueError

try:
    f()
except ValueError:
    print(f.rdepth, f.ncalls) # 1 1

try:
    f()
except ValueError:
    print(f.rdepth, f.ncalls) # 1 1 с try / finally и 2 2 без
```